# Where do I get sample code in C++ creating iterator for my own container?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, containers

I have been searching for sample code creating iterator for my own container, but I haven't really found a good example.  I know this been asked before ([Creating my own Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148540/c-creating-my-own-iterators)) but didn't see any satisfactory answer with examples.

I am looking for simple sample code to start how to design my own iterator.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301955.aspx) you could find good intro for creating custom iterators. Also take a look on the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) Library.

Comment: More specifically, the iterator_adaptor is a thing of beauty. With only a few lines of code you end up with a full-blown iterator.

Comment: `iterator_facade` is very helpful too

Answer (score 2):

I found [Matthew Wilson's 'extended STL'](http://synesis.com.au/publishing/xstl/) *very* educative on the subject.  Contains lots of do's and don'ts, plus tons of practical programming tips.  I think this guy really knows what he's doing.  (created libraries for that, too)

Answer (score 0):

Nicolai Josuttis has an example of a user defined iterator in his book: C++ Standard Library, a tutorial and a reference.

Here is the example online:

http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/iter/assoiter.hpp
http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/iter/assoiter.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this article which describes how to implement a custom virtual iterator for your classes: [article](http://www.ocoudert.com/blog/2010/07/07/how-to-write-abstract-iterators-in-c/)

It has one significant advantage - you can create an abstract base iterator class and inherit it with a few custom iterators for your own containers and maybe for some STL containers. So you will be able to use iterators dynamically - your functions will use a pointer to the abstract iterator class while other code will be able to choose what containers should be used.