# Custom STL-like iterator for RedBlackTree implementation

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I need an STL-like bidirectional iterator (operator<, begin(), rbegin(), end(), rend()) as an inner class to the following (I already spent considerable time all by myself to put together a working tree from a C# article in J of Object Tech and translated it to C++):

```
template<typename K, typename V> class rbtree {  
public:  
  rbtree(){  
    root = NULL;  
    numberElements = 0;  
    insertedNode = NULL;  
    nodeBeingDeleted = NULL; // Set in DeleteNode  
    siblingToRight = false; // Sibling of curNode  
    parentToRight = false; // Of grand parent  
    nodeToDeleteRed = false; // Color of deleted node  
  }  
  //...  
private:  
  struct Node {  
    // Fields  
    K key; // Generic object held by each node  
    Node* left; Node* right; Node* parent; // Links to children and parent  
    bool red;// = true; // Color of node  
    // Constructor  
    Node(){  
      red = true;  
    }  
    Node(K key, Node* parent) {  
      this->key = key;  
      this->parent = parent;  
      left = NULL; right = NULL;  
      red = true;  
    }  
  };  
  // Fields  
  Node* root;  
  //...  
};
```

Comment: Indent all code lines by four spaces (or more) for indentantion, syntax hilight and automatic escaping.

Comment: select your code and press the "101010" button

Comment: This reads like a spec for a piece of contract programming, not a question...

Comment: Indeed, where is the question?

Comment: I hope you did not forget to add the destructors after translating from C#

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! Trying to get up to speed here.  

Spec for contract programming? Sort of. <foolish grin> Spec and contractor: Professor; me student, but 57+. <g>  

Question is STL-like iterator (op++, begin(), end())matching the code fragment

Comment: As to David Rodriguez: Thanks, guess destructor is almost a no-brainer, but STL-like iterator not.  

Thx

Comment: In all honesty: when someone mentions a far away deadline that is well within the limits of the task, that his solution is a copy of someone else's C# implementation and what he got so far is minimal I don't suspect "learning" to be the motivation.

Comment: Hey, pmr, I came here, cuz Stackoverflow has been hyped as THE forum for answers to tricky questions (by Charles Franklin, Hanselman?). It IS a tricky one for me and I shared my motives honestly. I can hardly contain my disappointment about the debating club here.

Answer (score 2):

You would be suprised to know that a `std::set` is implemented as an Red-Black Tree. What are your reasons for writing one yourself?

For a real answer: Writing iterators isn't trivial. You should read about the common differences between iterator requirements. 
[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148540/c-creating-my-own-iterators)  is a kind of duplicate of your question and gives useful hints.

Comment: Reason for reinventing? Learning. (see comment above)  

Wouldn´t need to ask, if it was really trivial.
Thx

Comment: @gue22: If you're learning, then going and asking for the answer doesn't exactly teach you a whole lot. Open up the source code for `std::set<T>` and you can see a working implementation all day long.

Comment: Thanks, Billy, that´s what I´m going to try next. I simply hoped for a quick answer here, cuz I got an exam tomorrow and the deadline on Fri.