# Custom Template Iterator Reference

Tags: visual-c++, templates, iterator

Can any one recommend a good resource to refer on writing C++ custom template iterators??

Thank You!

Comment: What's a "custom template iterator"?

Comment: @ sbi - I meant an iterator class for a specific templated data structure written by me. Of course it might not be the technical term ;)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148540/c-creating-my-own-iterators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jossutis---[C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/)